# Django: Can I use a filter to return objects where a condition is valid across an entire related set?

Tags: python, django

My objects are set up similar to this:

```
class Event(Model):
    pass

class Inventory(Model):
    event = OneToOneField(Event)

    def has_altered_item_counts(self):
        return any(obj.field_one is not None or obj.field_two is not None for obj in self.itemcounts_set.all())

class ItemCounts(Model):
    inventory = ForeignKey(Inventory)
    field_one = IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    field_two = IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
```

Basically, I'd like to filter uniquely on `Event` where `inventory.has_altered_item_counts` would return `False`

I have

```
Q(inventory__itemcounts__field_one__isnull=True) & \
Q(inventory__itemcounts__field_two__isnull=True)
```

but that returns the event every time it meets those conditions. Given that result, I want to exclude that event if the number of times it appears is less than the total number of item counts. Does any of this make sense? Is this possible with `filter`? I really sort of need it to be, this is part of a programmatically built batch `update`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up doing it in a "get the PKs I'm trying to exclude first, then exclude those PKs"

Example in case anyone else is interested:

```
counts = Q(inventory__itemcounts__field_one__isnull=False) | \
         Q(inventory__itemcounts__field_two__isnull=False)

bad_pks = set(Event.objects.filter(counts).values_list("pk", flat=True))
Event.objects.exclude(pk__in=bad_pks).update(stuff)
```

Works like a charm.